# Calling a method on User in application_helper.rb returns undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a helper method that converts floats from imperial to metric. I have the following method in application_helper.rb:

```
  module ApplicationHelper
    def weight_conversion_factor
      if User.measurement_units == 'metric'
        0.453592
      elsif User.measurement_units == 'imperial'
        1
      end
    end
  end
```

If I call `current_user.measurement_units` in the view, it works great. When I try to call User.measurement_units in the `application_helper.rb` file, I get `undefined method`measurement_units' for #`

What am I missing here? Shouldn't I be able to just call `measurement_units` on User from within applicatoin_helper? `measurement_units` is a field in the User table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` is the class, not the instance. Use `current_user` in the helper method too:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def weight_conversion_factor
    return nil if current_user.nil?

    if current_user.measurement_units == 'metric'
      0.453592
    elsif current_user.measurement_units == 'imperial'
      1
    end
  end
end
```

**Alternatively,** This could go in the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Other code...

  def weight_conversion_factor
    if measurement_units == 'metric'
      0.453592
    elsif measurement_units == 'imperial'
      1
    else
      nil
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Ohh. Why is current_user available in the helper files, but not in the models? Is there a convention for where this kind of method should go? Should I be putting it in the `application_controller` or the `Application_helper`?

Comment: Helpers are available in the context of a request. The `current_user` is set when Rails receives a request. Models intentionally don't have access to anything related to the request cycle.

Comment: However, this does look like it belongs on the `User` model rather than in a helper. I'll update my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: When should I put something in the User model, and when should a create a helper method?

Comment: Things specifically related to the view, like which CSS classes to use or variables related only to display like `show_feature_x`, should live in a Helper related to the Model.

Answer (score 1):

If `measurement_units` is a field in the User table, you need to talk about a specific user (an **instance**) for the field to be accessible. For example, you could do any of these because they access a specific user's measurement_units:

```
current_user.measurement_units
User.new.measurement_units
User.last.measurement_units
User.find(1).measurement_units
```

If you want to be able to access measurement units on User (the **class**), you can define in your User.rb model:

```
def self.measurement_units
  ...
end
```

With this you can run: `User.measurement_units` without error.

In your case, you should simply run `current_user.measurement_units` in your helper.